# Poor performance of search suggestions in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am using ASP.Net MVC4 with Entity Framework 6 for server side operations and using jqgrid extensively in many pages as it's solves my purpose. Currently I am using server side paging and sorting.

Now I have implemented search suggestions referring [this demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010_withAutocomplete.zip). I have to show approx 70K suggestions initially but when I enter a character in search-box, my browser hangs. Sometimes it displays me suggestions but freezes to enter another character. I suppose it is happening because of large number of suggestions. I also looked [here](http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/performancelinqsearch) but not found a way.
(Oleg, I am looking for you man!)

Please help me out to improve the performance of search suggestions. My jqgrid is as follows:

```
 $("#DetailGrid").jqGrid({
    url: dataTobind,        
    datatype: dataType,      
    rownumbers: false,
    height: 400,
    rowNum: 25,        
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['ContactOrderNo', 'Contract Order Number', 'Serial Number', 'Model Number', 'Capacity', 'Contract Details'],
    colModel: [
                    { name: 'Capacity', width: 150, editable: false, hidden: true, sortable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
                    {
                        name: 'ContactOrderNo', width: 300, editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: false,searchoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                // it demonstrates custom item rendering
                                $(elem).autocomplete({ source: 'GetAutocompleteData' });
                                                      }
                        },                               

                            formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                            return '<a href="/OrderList/AddOrder/?ModelNo=' + cellvalue + '" >' + cellvalue + '</a>';
                        }
                    },

                       { name: 'SerialNumber', width: 150, sortable: false, editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
                       { name: 'ModelNo', width: 150, sortable: false, search:true, editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },
                        { name: 'Capacity', width: 150, sortable: false,search: false, editable: false, editrules: { required: true } },

                          {
                              name: 'ContractDetails', search: false, sortable: false, formatter: function (cellvalue)
                          {
                              var i, res = "", linkInfo;

                              if (cellvalue == null || !$.isArray(cellvalue)) {
                                  return "&nbsp;"; // empty cell in case or error
                              }

                              for (i = 0; i < cellvalue.length; i++) {
                                  linkInfo = cellvalue[i];
                                  res += (res.length > 0 ? "<br/> " : "") +
                                      '<a href="' + linkInfo.LinkSrc + '" target="_blank"  >' +
                                      linkInfo.LinkText + '</a>';
                              }

                              return res;
                          }
                              }                              

    ],

    rowList : [10,20,30,50],          
    viewrecords: true,        
    gridview: true,
    sortable: false,
    loadonce: false,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    autowidth: true,
    pager: '#DetailGridPager',            

});
jQuery("#DetailGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');

$("#DetailGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#DetailGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
$('#DetailGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, enableClear: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
```

And My controller is as follows :

```
   public JsonResult GetAutocompleteData(string term)
    {
        var cxt = new AppDataContext();
        return Json(cxt.Order.Where(t => t.ContactOrderNo.Contains(term)).Select(t => new { value = t.ContactOrderNo }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: Probably you should add `.Take(100)` or some other limit to the statement in `GetAutocompleteData` (before `.ToList()` of cause). In the case the method `GetAutocompleteData` will returns maximum 100 items. Moreover I would recommend you to try to use select2 [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UsageFormetterSelect2.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935). It could be helpful if one have many items whon which one need to choose.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Oleg! According to my use case I would prefer .Take(100) option rather select2, but in some cases I would be requiring Select2 so thanks for sharing the demo.

Comment: You are welcome! I use also both Autocomplete and select2 in my projects. Is the usage of `.Take(100)` could solve your problem?

Comment: Ok! I see , but in my project's scenario I have to use Autocomplete only. Now I am facing issue in user agent, Chrome renders the autocomplete results smoothly but Firefox hinders while I am entering only first character for search after 10 seconds it displays the results, can you suggest some tuning for it?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure that I understand your current problem. In any way you can consider to use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains` it it's possible and to create Index on the `ContactOrderNo` column. It should improve the time to getting the response. Probably you need to change `.Take(100)` to something like `.Take(20)`? All depend on your project and the clients requirements.

Comment: I am getting the results by using 'StartsWith' but I will try just after creating the index on 'ContactOrderNo'. Thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can add the call of `.Top` in the `GetAutocompleteData`, for example `.Top(100)` or `.Top(20)` before `.ToList()`. It will reduce the results of the corresponding SELECT statement. You should consider to use `.StartsWith` instead of `.Contains` if it's possible. In the case the SELECT could use the Index in the database it such exist on the field `ContactOrderNo`.