# Jgrid defining custom formatter dynamically

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have a grid with colModel defined as:

```
colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true},
      ...
   ]
```

After the grid is created I want to bind a custom formatter with the column. How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setColProp` method for example to modify some specific column in `colModel`. You can dynamically modify the most properties inclusive `formatter`. It's important that the formatter will be used during filling the `<tbody>` (the data part) of the grid. Thus the modification of the `formatter` will be seen after the next filling the grid. Thus one can make modification of `formatter` inside of `beforeProcessing` callback or one should trigger `reloadGrid` after the modification. I recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) for more information and an example of the implementation.